# Can't locate object method "simple_request" via package "RPC::XML::Client::new: Unable to get RPC::XML::Parser object"

Tags: perl, oop, xml-rpc, perl-module, confluence

There seems to be a dozen questions related to missing methods and OO Perl on here, but from what I can see, a lot of them are related to home-made Perl modules. My question deals with an apparently missing method in a CPAN module, however. I am trying to use the `Confluence::Client::XMLRPC` module to create a script that will upload text to our Confluence Wiki page whenever it is called.

I am programming on our private server and have no access to CPAN directly. I had to download all the required packages manually as tarballs from another box and FTP them over. I then used `make` to install them in the proper order, paying attention to dependencies.

Additionally, it is company policy to install all additional Perl modules in a custom `/lib` folder in our home directory, and we are not allowed to alter the system's Perl lib (though we can still use the default packages). I also do not have root priveleges.

Right now I am simply trying to test out the functionality of the XML-RPC server with this simple code ([pulled mostly from the Confluence module CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~hjansen/Confluence-Client-XMLRPC-2.5/lib/Confluence/Client/XMLRPC.pm)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use RPC::XML::Parser;
use Confluence::Client::XMLRPC;

my $username = 'username';
my $password = 'password';
my $proxyurl = '.../confluence/rpc/xmlrpc';

my $wiki = Confluence::Client::XMLRPC->new($username, $password, $proxyurl);
```

I should note here that I do not use a `use lib` here because my custom lib directory is already included in `$PERL5LIB` (maybe this is the source of the error - methods being overwritten?)

The code spits out the following error:

`Can't locate object method "simple_request" via package "RPC::XML::Client::new: Unable to get RPC::XML::Parser object" (perhaps you forgot to load "RPC::XML::Client::new: Unable to get RPC::XML::Parser object"?) at /home/myID/lib/share/perl5/Confluence/Client/XMLRPC.pm line 141.`

I'd suspect a coding error here on my part if it were a custom module, but it's a standard CPAN module that made, tested, and installed perfectly fine. I have verified that the package RPC/XML/Parser.pm definitely exists. I tried to print the @INC locations to verify I was using the correct modules:

```
print($INC{"Confluence/Client/XMLRPC.pm"}, "\n");
print($INC{"RPC/XML/Client.pm"}, "\n");
print($INC{"RPC/XML/Parser.pm"}, "\n");
```

This prints out:

```
/home/myID/lib/share/perl5/Confluence/Client/XMLRPC.pm
/home/myID/lib/share/perl5/RPC/XML/Client.pm
/home/myID/lib/share/perl5/RPC/XML/Parser.pm
```

which looks pretty much as I expected. Been tearing my hair out ever since trying to find out what's wrong, but have not yet made much more progress than that. Any suggestions and/or advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Additional information:**

- perl: `revision 5 version 10 subversion 1`
- fields: `2.14`
- %ENV: `PERL5LIB="/home/myID/lib/share/perl5"`
- @INC:

  - /home/myID/lib/share/perl5
  - /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  - /usr/local/share/perl5
  - /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  - /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  - /usr/lib64/perl5
  - /usr/share/perl5

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that `simply_request` is being looked up in package **RPC::XML::Client::new** Please post your `perl` and `fields` version information.

Comment: Ah, I can get the `perl` version, but how would I get the `fields` version info?

Comment: `perl -Mfields -e 'print $fields::VERSION'`

Comment: Your arguments to `Confluence::Client::XMLRPC->new` are out of order. It expects `( <URL>, <user>, <pass> )`. This might cause a cascading error, since your RPC client is now using your username as a URL.

Comment: Oh, good catch on that one. Didn't solve the issue, but thank you! I've added my version info plus %ENV and @INC.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I overlooked some too-convenient-to-be-true examples that came with the source code. A five second look at `upload_files.pl` in `Confluence-Client-XMLRPC-2.5/examples` shows that I was only missing a single line of code, `use lib qw(../lib);`, right before the `use Confluence::Client::XMLRPC;`. Everything worked like clockwork after that.

Sadly, I have no idea what `use lib qw(../lib);` does right now, so I think the lesson here is to learn more about OO Perl and just Perl libraries in general. If I had stopped to read the CPAN page in the first place, I might have saved myself mountains of time.